# Oracle SQLDeveloper: How to search which tables have a column matching given query?

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Developer, how do I find which table has a column that matches a specified search query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select table_name, column_name 
from user_tab_columns 
where column_name like '%'|| '&columnPattern' || '%'
```

**`User_tab_columns`** for your own tables. Otherwise **`dba_tab_columns`** or **`all_tab_columns`**